# Factorial function in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and am just learning the syntax and various functions. I would like to know if

```
x=reduce((lambda x,y: x*y) , [x for x in range(5) if x > 0])
```

is a correct function for calculating the factorial of a number ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you new to programming or new to Python? You should use the `factorial` function from the `math`module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something along the lines of http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html

```
# beginner

def fac(n):
    f = 1
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        f *= i
        i += 1
    return f

# advanced beginner

def fac(n):
    return n * fac(n - 1) if n > 1 else 1

# intermediate

def fac(n):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(1, n + 1))

# advanced intermediate

import operator
def fac(n):
    return reduce(operator.mul, xrange(1, n + 1))

# professional

import math
print math.factorial(5)

# guru

import scipy.misc as sc
print sc.factorial(5, exact=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

Short:

```
x = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, range(1,5))
```

Shorter, Instead of a lambda:

```
from operator import mul
x = reduce(mul, range(1,5))
```

Or Shortest, from math module (thanks to hop):

```
from math import factorial
factorial(4) # range/xrange above does not include the upper value
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much -- though if you want 5!, you should do `range(6)`. Also, a small stylistic issue: you should surround your generator expression with parentheses instead of brackets, so that a temporary list doesn't need to be constructed. Finally, the if-clause isn't necessary -- just use the two-argument version of `range`.

Comment: or even just use `range(1,6)` in place of the entire list/generator comprehension.

Comment: Hah, you beat me to it.

Comment: And on top of it, you can use ``operator.mul`` instead of the lambda (``import operator`` first).

Answer (score 1):

```
def factorial(n):return reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,[1]+range(1,n+1))
```

Comment: Better: `reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, xrange(1, n+1), 1)`

Comment: I use def, to define a function factorial(n), so each line you need to do factorial function, just call factorial(n), so you avoid to write reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, xrange(1, n+1), 1) each line you need it

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using recursion:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)
```

Anyway, it's better to use [math.factorial](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.factorial).